# Finding slope in General For of First-Order Regression Model with Quantitative and Qualitative

Tags: r

How do I find slope for a General form of First-Order Regression Model with Quantitative and Qualitative variables? So what I am trying to figure out is how can I figure out slope so I can fill in *B*1x1 + *B*x2 ... etc. Once I figure out how to get the slopes I can figure out the rest. This is where I am stuck in my problem.

So I'm trying to figure this type of General form out: e(y)= B0 + B1x1 + B2x2.. I have more variables but you get the jest.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried youtube, books, even asking my professor (Taking forever to answer), and did searches. Nothing seems to line up with R programming language.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking.  The `lm()` function in R can handle any combination of quantitative (numeric) and qualitative (= categorical = `factor` type) variables ... ??